# Scale bar for polar plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label

I've created a polar plot and do not like the overlap of the y-tick labels and the plot data. Instead I'd like to create a scale bar to present the y-tick information. Is there a way to turn the y-axis labels into a scale bar for polar plots?  An example of what I'd like to output:

[image: example]

```
fig = plt.figure( figsize = (4,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = 'polar')
c = ax.plot(polar_df['Position'],np.log2(polar_df['Total']) )

ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
# Labels
# convert radian to degrees
label1 = polar_df.iloc[4000]['Position'] * 180 / np.pi
label2 = polar_df.iloc[8000]['Position'] * 180 / np.pi
label3 = polar_df.iloc[12000]['Position'] * 180 / np.pi
label4 = polar_df.iloc[16000]['Position'] * 180 / np.pi
label_pos_lis = [label1,label2,label3,label4]
# set the locations and labels of the angular gridlines
plt.thetagrids((label1,label2,label3,label4), labels = ('4000', '8000', '12000','16000') )
locs, labels = plt.yticks()

ax.set_theta_direction(-1)  # theta direction clockwise
ax.grid(False)  #remove background lines
ax.set_yticklabels([]) #Remove tick information
ax.set_rmax(np.log2(polar_df['Total'].max()) * .1 + np.log2(polar_df['Total'].max()))
plt.tight_layout()
```

What I currently have:

[image: current output]